# Multidimensional Array modify values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'd changed, the data in this line.

```
$fileConv = $_GET['file']; // It retrieves data to add.
$file = intval($fileConv); // Conversion

$ArrayNotes = array (
  0 => array ('titre' => 'aaa','ref' => 'aaa','date' => 'aaa','like' => aaa,'url' => 'aaa'),
  1 => array ('titre' => 'aaa1','ref' => 'aaa1','date' => 'aaa1','like' => aaa1,'url' => 'aaa1') // my array
);

$like = $ArrayNotes[$file]['like'] + 1; // The only data that changes.

$donnee = array("titre" => $ArrayNotes[$file]['titre'], "ref" => $ArrayNotes[$file]['ref'],"date" => $ArrayNotes[$file]['date'], "like" => $like, "url" => $ArrayNotes[$file]['url']); // Change Data
```

As stated, I want to know how to change this data directly.

Example : To add a new line :

```
array_push($ArrayNotes, $donnee);
$var_str = var_export($ArrayNotes, true);
$var = "<?php\n\n\$ArrayNotes = $var_str;\n\n?>";
file_put_contents('content.php', $var);
```

Thanks you for your help.

Comment: I somehow doubt it, that `aaa` and `aaa1` are constants? Also what are you trying to do?

Comment: `aaa` and `aaa1` are constants or..? Also. What are you trying to do with that line? : `$var = "<?php\n\n\$ArrayNotes = $var_str;\n\n?>";` I think you are complicating your life way more than you can actually imagine :P

Comment: aaa & aaa1 is not constants it's the data on my array.
The purpose of this line and adding <?Php $my_array ?>.
It's clear that I could could find more simpe ... :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be as easy as the following:

```
$ArrayNotes[$file]['like'] = 1234;
```

And if you just wish to add one to the existing field, you may do:

```
$ArrayNotes[$file]['like'] += 1;
```

Comment: Really ? ... I'm very noob ! Thanks you

Comment: No Problem! I'm glad if it helped :-)
And don't bother if it's not the "best code" for your purpose, we're all trying, learning and getting better. It just takes time.

Comment: Another thing you could try to optimize this code is using PHP's serialize() and unserialize() functions to store an array in a separate file.
serialize: http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php
unserialize: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php